# Rewards for placing a Pokemon on a gym

Tags: pokemon-go

If you have already placed a Pokemon on a gym and pushed the timer button and gotten paid then in the middle of those 21 hours you place another one on a different gym do you still get paid for that one and when.

Answer (score 3):

No, you only receive rewards the moment you click the button.

If you add more Pokemon at gyms you will notice the number on the defender bonus button increases. When the timer is up you can click it again to receive the reward * how many Pokemon you have in gyms (up to a maximum of 10).

Comment: I did not know about the rewards for the first 20 levels.  Damn game tells you nothing...